# Screwdrivers, scalpel and knife in checked baggage

Tags: usa, luggage, hand-luggage, tsa

I will be traveling from US to Europe in 2 weeks and wanted to buy toolkit from [iFixIt](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Tools/Pro-Tech-Toolkit/IF145-307?o=4) which contains knife, scalpel and screwdrivers.

Am I allowed to put it in the checked baggage? I was thinking that scalpel could be a problem as it might be treated as medical equipment.

Comment: Howdy and welcome.  This is a question for the airline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of that can go into the hold. As a generic rule of thumb, the only things that can't are those that can damage the airplane should something go wrong: corrosive fluids, flammable and explosive things. Then there is mace spray and radioactive materials and other incredible things noone sane would have anyways... See https://www.aircanada.com/no/en/aco/home/plan/baggage/restricted-and-prohibited-items.html for example.

Comment: According to the [TSA](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/knives), "Any sharp objects in checked bags should be sheathed or securely wrapped to prevent injury to baggage handlers and inspectors.". It looks as though the kit in question does that.